# Select rows from table where values by date stop and then start using SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of values with counts by dates in columns and then a key field.  I need to identify the rows where the key values match and the counts overlap and either reduce to 0 or increase from 0.

As an example:

```
Value   20150401    20150402    20150403   20150404    Key
1        200         250         0          0           A
2        0           120         200        175         A
3        0           0           50         100         C
4        500         235         60         0           D
5        300         130         75         0           C
```

In this case I would want rows 1 & 2, 3 & 5 to return because they shared the same key and there was an overlap of a day when 1 reduced to 0 and 2 increased from 0.  The same for 3&5. To further complicate it the number of date columns can fluctuate so the table won't always have just 4 days worth of data.

Comment: So you need very complex query for a  garbage table.

Comment: If it was my problem, I would find a way to pivot the table so there was a row for each date.  That becomes a table you can join to itself to get your desired result.